# Why are there piyyutim for the beginning of first day Rosh Hashanah musaf, but not for the second day (in Nusach Ashkenaz)?

Tags: song-poetry, rosh-hashanah-new-year, musaf

On the first day of Rosh Hashanah at *musaf*, Ashkenazim recite *piyyutim* as part of the first three *berachot* of the *amidah*, composed by R. Elazar HaKalir. On the second day, no such *piyyutim* are recited and we find no *piyyutim* until (*lekeil orech din* and) *unetaneh tokef* and *kedushah*.

From Double AA I understand that this form of *piyyut* is unusual for a *musaf amidah*. (The only other time we find them is on Yom Kippur.) So my question is, why do these *piyyutim* appear for the first day of Rosh Hashanah? And, if there is some reason why they are appropriate for Rosh Hashanah, why only on the first day and not the second?

(I understand that for whatever reason R. Elazar HaKalir only wrote one set of *piyyutim* for Rosh Hashanah, but given that he felt it was appropriate to have this form of *piyyut* at *musaf*, why did no-one else compose *piyyutim* for *musaf* of the second day, like R. Shimon HaGadol did for *shacharit* of the second day?)

Comment: What's about תפילת טל and תפילת גשם then?

Comment: @kazi that's a Shivata not a Kedushta. Different poetic structure. Shivata is the normal Musaf Piyut form, like on Shabbat Shekalim.

Comment: One easy way to tell the difference between the two is whether the piyyutim are prefaced by the introdutory _missod_. As far as I recall we have this whenever piyyutim are recited in shacharit, indicating that they are _kedushtot_, but never at _musaf_ (apart from Yom Kippur and first day Rosh Hashanah), where we have _shivatot_.

Comment: Interestingly, although this is the Minhog Ashkenaz and Minhog Polin (albeit Ashkenaz does not do לא-ל עורך דין), Minhag Tzorfas (France) does have a full Kerovo here on page 234 http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Goldschmidt_Machzor_Rosh_Hashonah.pdf

Comment: It's possible that the proposed piyutim for 2nd day Musaf were moved to 2nd day Shacharit. Note that the 2nd day Shacharit is significantly longer than 1st day. (BTW, taght's not afar-fetched reasoning. It's part of the reasoning as to why *L'el Orech Din* is moved to Musaf on the 2nd day for many minhagim. There is some "balancing" done.)

Comment: @DoubleAA One doesn't expect a שבעתא for yom tov musaf, and most שבעתות for yom tov were written for maariv. Tal and geshem are exceptions rather than the rule here.

Comment: @magicker72 What else would you expect for a 'mefuyyat' musaf?

Comment: @DoubleAA Probably very little. Ezra Fleischer contends that in minhag E"Y (to whichi belonged many early paytanim) the musaf was plain, since the shaḥarit already was lengthened by a קדושתא (and I haven't read anything with a contrary opinion). Of course, in Ashkenaz/Sefarad the piyyutim got re-arranged and re-assigned, so you'll find all sorts of piyyutim with musaf.

Comment: The Rosh (Brachot 5:21) suggests that in the time of Elazar HaKalir, they had only one day of Rosh HaShanah in Israel (or parts of Israel), since they would מקדש על פי הראיה, and this is why he only wrote for the first day. However, I've read scholarly opinions explicitly to the contrary, so take this suggestion with a grain of salt.

Comment: @magicker72 Even if that’s the case, that should not have stopped someone else writing piyutim for musaf of the second day

Comment: @JoelK It's only a comment, not an answer. But it's worth noting that there *are* other piyyutim for second day, they're just not usually printed in Artscroll/Koren. You can find lots of piyyutim in Daniel Goldschmidt's Rosh Hashanah maḥzor.

Comment: @magicker72 Then I stand by Shivata being the normal Musaf form, even if the use of a form is minimal. It's the default form for any 7-blessing repetition without Kedusha [as determined by the Kedusha practice in old israel].

Comment: Thought I had this year: maybe the piyyutim for the first day were only intended for Shabbat, with no extra piyyutim on weekdays to minimize interruption after the earlier shofar blasts. cc @magicker